# Why would I only lose 10 rep for reversal of serial voting?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Apparently I gained a fan.  Flattering as it is I noticed this when on **one site** I lost **10 rep**.  I've checked other sites and can't find any other similar or matching adjustment.

I'm actually quite curious now how that adds up.  If I'd lost 100 rep I wouldn't have thought anything of it.  But since this "correction" results in the reversal of only a single vote I'm mildly amused.

Can anyone elaborate on why reversing "serial voting" could result in losing only one vote?

Comment: (I can't prove it's the same situation, but I consider it very likely.)

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks. I didn't spot that question in my background search.  Yes it looks like the same issue.