# "Serial voting was reversed" on a community where I have only 1 post

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I got a "-10 Serial voting was reversed" on the Buddhism community - a community that the only post I made was a question in 2014. The last reputation I got from that question was in 2016.

Does serial voting tracking work on reputation that happened at least 5 years ago?

EDIT:
While [Non-serial voting corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362020/non-serial-voting-corrected) can be an answer, it doesn't confirm what happened and doesn't explain why it's happening on reputation earned 5 years ago. But it does answer some of my questions, so I'm editing them out.

Comment: Related: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/335251)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-serial voting corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362020/non-serial-voting-corrected)

Comment: If you [check the time](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/1009/roberto?tab=reputation) it was before 0200, while the reversal script runs at 0300, so it was an employee; possibly the person upvoted a number of people and gave you one too, all of their efforts were manually reversed. All the *other* votes belonged to other people. --- An exact answer would come from an employee who checks exactly what happened, if telling you wouldn't narrow it down to too few a number of people. --- Same thing here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372199/282094

Comment: I'm moving to leave this open since the cause may not be the same as in the proposed duplicate, i.e. a user using a script to mass-vote on others' posts to game badges, especially since the vote in question was cast at least five years ago. It'd be nice to have a staff response here as to what happened; if it was indeed the same cause, then staff can close it.

Comment: The answer from animuson is identical to any answer that would be put here - it's the broader voting behavior that's problematic, not voting targeted at a specific person - we can't really explain each and every case of this happening.

Comment: Roberto, if you wish to be certain that a particular person sees [what you wrote in your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372446/serial-voting-was-reversed-on-a-community-where-i-have-only-1-post#comment1243881_372446) you need to precede her user name with an @ it usually indicates that a particular person is reachable by a pop-up at the upper left of the comment window, there are a few additional people *@-replyable* who don't show up. --- See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/282094

Comment: Thank you @Rob, always wondered why this sometimes doesn't work, I had thought it never worked and I was crazy for thinking it did, so I stopped using :)

Comment: @Catija No but you could confirm that it happens with really old stuff too :)